# Way to see the whole commit history of a repo in Egit/TortoiseGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control, tortoisegit, egit

I'm looking for a way to see, though egit, to the whole history of my current git repo. From what it looks like, egit's "Show in History" will only show commits up to the current commit. With this I mean that if I do commit1 and commit2 and then decide to do checkout of the first, running "Show in History" of the project will not show up commit2.

Is there any way that allows me to see the whole history of the repo? I guess that'll be somehting on the lines of the `git log master` console command.

In other words, if you do checkout at any time your initial commit, how are you supposed to later be able to checkout the newer commits if your history won't show them?

I've been checking out, and it seems TortoiseGit "suffers" from the same problem. Is it indeed a problem or is just me that's not doing thing as we're supposed to?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just open up `gitk --all` and look at the top. This will show you the entire history. I haven't worked with the other tools but if they don't have an --all switch, use gitk.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

There is actually a button *Show all Branches and Tags* in the Eclipse history view to show all commits. See screenshot for more detail:

[image]

(It was already mentioned by L2G, but i did not had enough reputation to post a comment there.)

Comment: This button doesnt work. I dont know if its because I merge the branches after working with them, but it would be nice to see them all like in your picture. Instead I see just one big long line, as if they all are one branch :-(. But then again, its usually (if not each time) a "fastforward", which might be the reason x)

Comment: yes, a fastforward is considered as a linear extension of the history. You can change that behavior by adding '--no-ff' to the merge command.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the toolbar under the History tab, there's a little icon of a path forking into two downward arrows. Its tooltip says "Show All Branches and Tags." I think that will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem too.

There is a 'Git Reflog' view available on the latest versions (eclipse Luna Service Release 1 [4.4.1] with eGit 3.5.1).

For background see:  http://aniszczyk.org/2011/06/26/git-reflog-and-eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the context menu when right clicking on the repo folder. Go to TortoiseGit -> Show Log

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Open Git Repositories in Eclipse.
Step 2: Expand the Branches and right click on the Working Copy branch and click 'Open in Commit Viewer'. The latest commit to this branch shows up.
Step 3: On the latest commit in the viewer screen, click on the top right-most button 'Show in History'. The history opens up in a tab below. Refer to snapshot, below.
[image: Git History in Eclipse Egit]